# Excel VBA, sorting, saving, closing, then opening

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, recover

I have two Excel files, file1.xlsm and file2.xlsm; I have a data table in one, and soemthing else in the other. In the second file I also have a button which opens the first file.

In the first file I have a button which sorts all data using column A as the key and a second button to save and exit.

My code for sorting:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
       .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A3"), Order:=xlAscending
       .SetRange Range("A3:AF" & lRow)
       .Header = xlNo
       .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem is that after I sort, save and exit I cannot re-open the same workbook through VBA (the button does nothing); I can click on the file, then it opens but gives me an error that there were problems, yet Excel can recover. The error in error log:

> Errors were detected in file 'C:\file1.xlsm'
>   Removed Records: Sorting from
>   /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

The button to save is just closing the workbook with `SaveChanges:=True`.

Why is this happening and how can it be rectified?

Comment: This *"Errors were detected in file"* means that your file is corrupt. Try saving it in the binary `.xlsb` format (this might fix it) and then save at again in XML format `.xlsm`. I often had issues with the XML format and file corruption. So for big data I recommend to use the binary format (it's a bit more efficient and produces smaller files).

Comment: wouldn't it delete all my macros and buttons inside? I will try and get back with results.

Comment: No, the binary xlsb supports macros too.

Answer (score 0):

This Error

> Errors were detected in file

means that your file is corrupt.

In many cases converting the file into the binary `.xlsb` format repairs the file. After that you can save at again in XML format `.xlsm`.

Nevertheless, I often had issues with the XML format and file corruption. So for big data I recommend to use the binary format (it's a bit more efficient and produces smaller files too).

Comment: Sorry, but it turns out not to be the best approach, as if I use the VBA to sort the data  the way I showed above, both xlsm and xlsb get corrupted, although not always.

Comment: Try if it happen with a completely new file. Saving in a different format *can* help but sometimes the file stays corrupt. Try it with a completely new file that is not corrupt.